# Sorting a Rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, sorting

I have a table `A(:name, :address, :country_id)`. I run this query

```
ids = [1,2,3]
@result = A.where(country_id: ids)
```

But, I want to get the results in this order : `records containing country_id = 2 first, then 1 and then 3`.

How should I write this query?

Edit :

```
@people = []
@result.each do |r|
  @people.push([r,r.name])
end
```

I have an array @people of arrays now and want to sort it. What should be the query now?

Another Edit :

```
@people.sort_by! {|p| preferred_order.index(p.first.country_id)}
```

This worked.

Comment: More information is needed: why are you doing this? Are there always 3 results?

Comment: There are many results. I want to display results in such an order that the rows containing country_id = 2 are displayed first, then 1 and then 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort_by` :

```
ids = [1,2,3]
preferred_order = [2,1,3]

@result = A.where(country_id: ids)
@result.sort_by! { |u| preferred_order.index(u.country_id) }
```

Comment: What if I have copied my 'result' into an array 'people'. What should I do now?

Comment: Then try `@people.sort_by! { |u| preferred_order.index(u.country_id) }` and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be adding an extra column

```
 rails g migration add_sortorder_to_A sort_order:integer
```

Then add a

```
before_save :update_sort_order

def update_sort_order
  if self.country_id == 1
    self.update_attributes(sort_order:2)
  elsif self.country_id ==2
    self.update_attributes(sort_order:1)
 ........
end
```

Alternatively, put your sort_order in the countries and sort on that.

Alternatively, create a dynamic field which will give you the sort_order.

There is probably a more elegant way of doing this, but this should work in a quick and dirty way and allow you to use standard activerecord queries and sorting. (i.e. you can just forget about it once you've done it the once)

Comment: Alternatively, do what Sharvy said. Much more elegant... :)